# Angular2 join string in expression

Tags: angular

I would like to join a string in an expression in Angular2, though seem unable to do so. (Specifically in the attr.href of the a tag.

For example, assume that I have a url made of '/page/id', and the ID is stored in a variable.

```
   <a [attr.href]="/page/{{id}}">link</a>
```

This will not work, because we can not use {{}} syntax in an expression.

I am not sure how I would go about joining strings here.

Comment: haha too quick both @Gunter and @Thierry for answer. well apart from answer see here explanation of when to use `{{}}` and `[]` property binding http://stackoverflow.com/a/36528964/5043867

Comment: You don't need `attr` in this case. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah they were amazingly fast actually!

Comment: Hmm No doubt ! @DylanMeeus

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<a [attr.href]="'/page/' + id">link</a>
```

Since in this case you can't use interpolation (because of `[...]`). Angular2 will try to evaluate the expression and you can use string value delimited with quotes here.

Comment: This solved the problem, thanks! I need to wait some minutes before I can accept this as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `[...]` and `{{..}}` together either

```
 <a attr.href="/page/{{id}}">link</a>
```

or

```
 <a [attr.href]="'/page/' + id">link</a>
```

There is no need for `attr` because the `href` property reflects to the `href` attribute automatically ([**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/T1NLnb?p=preview)).

```
 <a href="/page/{{id}}">link</a>
```